# Cant delete table under one to many relationship

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have these 3 relevant tables below :
[image]

I have a form. Say it is called `fmEditPurchase`. Inside that form, I can edit `Purchase` informations, and add / delete `PurchasedProduct`.
[image]

There can be many changes in that form, **but the changes will only be applied** if I click on the save button, which returns `DialogResult.OK` to parent form. Below method is located in the main form.

```
    private void Purchase_EditPurchase(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvPurchase.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            int index = dgvPurchase.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = dgvPurchase.Rows[index];

            int id = (int)selectedRow.Cells["ID"].Value;

            Purchase edit = null;

            using (var context = new dbKrunchworkContext())
            {
                edit = context.Purchases.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

                if (edit != null)
                {
                    fmAddEditPurchase editForm = new fmAddEditPurchase(edit);

                    if (editForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        //Section 1
                        foreach (var item in editForm.DeletedPP)
                        {
                            context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                            context.Entry(item.Product).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                        }

                        //Section 2
                        context.Entry(editForm.Purchase).State = EntityState.Modified;

                        //Section 3
                        foreach (var item in editForm.Purchase.PurchasedProducts)
                        {
                            context.Entry(item.Product).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
                        }

                        tslbMessage.Text =
                            string.Format("Product Data Edited");

                        context.SaveChanges();
                        Purchase_RefreshDGVPurchase();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, to summarize, the changes on a particular `Purchase` record can include the removal / addition of `PurchasedProduct` and every other fields, which everything will be applied at eafter the Save button is pressed.

**The problem is, when I'm editing, and removing a `PurchasedProduct` and saving, below error popped up.**

[image]

The problem persist even after I rearrange the order of section 1, 2, and 3 (Look at top code to see where are the section 1,2,3, which are marked in the comments.).

I also can't do the `SaveChanges()` in the `fmEditPurchase`, since it's able to be cancelled to make 0 changes.

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: The context is trying to change a primary key to `NULL`, in this case `Product_ID`. I assume that the property allow `NULL` in database, change it to `NOT NULL` so context will know that if the value is going to be `NULL` it will be deleted instead

Comment: What are the referential integrity constraints on the `PurchasedProduct` table?

Comment: @rodolfo it's a shared PK. So it can't be null.

Comment: @brandon : what's referential integrity constraints? Never heard of that before.

Comment: Why `Product_ID` is a PK?, a Product can´t be purchased twice?

Comment: @MosesAprico You may need to read up on some database design in that case. What the error there is telling you is that you're trying to delete a row from your table where you (or the DBA?) has specifically said that you can't. I can't tell what object you're deleting from your image. Is it a `PurchasedProduct` or the product itself?

Comment: @Rodolfo a purchase record can't have 2 PurchasedProduct record with a same product (just add the quantity instea). It can be purchased more than once, if only the Purchase record is different

Comment: @Brandon it is the PurchasedProduct. Hmm. I think i should be able to delete it. Since it's basically just a "connector table" for many-to-many relationship between Purchase and Product.

Comment: According to "_(just add the quantity instea)_" you don't need to set the PK to `Product_ID`. FK should be enough. If you wanna increase the quantity just look for the record searching by `Product_ID`, update it and save. In that way deleting will be possible

Comment: @MosesAprico  That's my point. If you're trying to remove a product from a purchase and that's a valid workflow but EF is telling you you can't, you need to rethink your DB constraints.

Comment: @Rodolfo i see. Yeah. That's what my lecturer said how it should be done. Haha. Thanks for the insights though :)

Comment: @Brandon i see. Yeah. That's what my lecturer said how it should be done. Haha. Thanks for the insights though if any 1 of u can post on "the answer", i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment:

> a purchase record can't have 2 PurchasedProduct record with a same
>   product (just add the quantity instea)

You don't need to set the PK to `Product_ID`. FK should be enough. If you wanna increase the quantity just look for the record searching by `Product_ID`, update it and save. In that way deleting will be possible.

Comment: I'm not on computer yet, so i'll accept it as soon as i've test it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, sorry for a long time to respond. It still fails. `The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.` when I call `context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Deleted;`. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it, while Rodolfo's answer contribute to the solution, but it's not enough.

These are what I did :

1. I add my database context as parameter to the edit dialog constructor, and also a field inside that to store the context.

   ```
   private dbKrunchworkContext context;
   public fmAddEditPurchase(dbKrunchworkContext context)
   {
       //Bla bla
       this.context = context;
       //Bla bla
   }
   ```
2. Before I initialize & show the dialog, I initialize the context using `using(var context = new dbKrunchworkContext) { }` and pass the value to the dialog.

   ```
   using (var context = new dbKrunchworkContext())
   {
       edit = context.Purchases.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

       if (edit != null)
       {
           fmAddEditPurchase editForm = new fmAddEditPurchase(context, edit);

           if (editForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
           {
               //Blabla
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the new dialog, every time I'm going to use a context, I use the context field instead of using a newly instatiated one.

   ```
   private void RefreshPurchasedProduct()
   {
       BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();

       //Bla bla

       bi.DataSource = Purchase.PurchasedProducts.
           Join(context.Products, x => x.Product.ID, y => y.ID, (x, y) =>
               new { y.Product_Name, x.Price, x.Quantity }).ToList();

       //Bla bla
   }
   ```

This way, there'll be no (annoying) `The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.`

Hope this helps anyone stumbled upon this similar problem of mine.

P.S. Some of the solution out there may prefer solve it with the static context, never tried it, but if me, I prefer this way, since it'll be cleaner this way, and less code to maintain.